# VC++ Warning C4356: static data member cannot be initialized via derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, static, warnings

The following code issues this warning, but it seems to work fine as both A::st and B::st are initialized and actually represent the same string. In my understanding this is malformed code and it should not compile (I checked clang). I wonder why VC++ doesn't issue an error instead of a warning?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    static const std::string st;
};

class B : public A
{

};

const std::string B::st = "abcd"; //warning C4356: 'A::st': static data member cannot be initialized via derived class

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::st << std::endl; // outputs "abcd"
    std::cout << B::st << std::endl; // outputs "abcd"
}
```

Comment: The language standard just talks about issuing a "diagnostic". It doesn' t say if they are to be called warnings or errors (or something else).

Answer (score 1):

From Inheritance definition everything is fine
because B is an A plus some additional things, but think on what you have defined!
You defined a static const string in  class a.
Because it is static it is global and will be the same for all instances of A and B.
Because of that even direct instances of A will be initialized with "abcd"
and if you have a D that also derives from A but not from B it will contain abcd 
and because it is static you are not able to define a B containing "abcd" and a D containing "efgh"
I have not tried but I am quite sure you will run into some trouble
if you define

```
clase D :public A
{
};
const std:string d:st = "efgh";
```

Even if compiler only tells a warning it prpbably depends on link order what will be the content of A::st.
it might be "abcd" or "efgh" but either d::st will be "abcd" or B::st will be "efgh" you are not able to define "abcd" for B and "efgh" for D because it is static.